# How to access AMT SOL from Windows?

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, intel-amt

I have a program which gives debug output to a serial port (running in a small OS framework) - but no output shell / window. I need therefore to access the information from another computer.

The "server" computer has AMT and in BIOS I can enable serial-over-lan. Now I have the very stupid problem, that I do not know how to access the serial-over-lan thing from another computer.

My main "client" computer has Windows 8. Is there any possibility  or tool to acces the SOL information from windows?

(The tools which i found yet are for Linux only like amtterm or gamt.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a simple SOL .exe typetool for Windows yet. I usually ssh into a Linux server and just run the ipmitool command:

ipmitool -I lanplus -H  -U root -a sol activate

Apparently you can do the same command with Cygwin. I haven't tried it yet:
http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-do-sol-serial-over-lan-aka-console-redirection-dell-servers

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907005/ipmitool-for-windows?newreg=dafbce07c8f942deb95708c870de3d5e